# Create django generic class view method

Tags: python, django

I am new to OOP and everything else. I would like to create a method for a django generic class (DetailView) that calls subprocess as the view is called. This is what I have currently and it works fine:

```
class ThingsObject(SingleObjectMixin):
    template_name = 'thingsdb/stuff.html'
    queryset = Things.objects.all()


class ThingsView(ThingsObject, generic.DetailView):
    pass
```

So I would like to define a method that calls subprocess on a script with an argument containing the request object, something like this:

```
def foo(self):
    bar= "".join(["python", "bar.py", str(self.object)])
    subprocess.call(bar, shell=True)
```

I would like have the method run as the view is called. The response should be what that script returns, which I would like to add as context to the template.

I realise that the answer to this is probably extremely basic to your average programmer but  I have been playing around with some solutions for a while, but have not gotten anywhere. Hence I am asking how would you do this?

My thoughts are perhaps I should override the dispatch method to include running the script and returning the extra context. But to be honest, I have no idea what I am doing in class based views.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping to achieve here. Why call a Python script in a subprocess (rather than just importing it and calling it)? And what is the response supposed to be?

Comment: sorry, I must have been drunk when penning the original question, I left out a vital ingredient - the response should be what that script returns, which I would like to add as context to the template. Subprocess is not vital but I was using it because I considered it as a way of adding args to when the script is called. I guess I could do this more directly. I will update my question with this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the result of a script to the context, then you should call it from `get_context_data`. The result of that is a dict, so you can add your data there.

Note that the result of `subprocess.call` is simply the return code of the script, not whatever the script outputs. There are various other ways to get the actual output, but as I mentioned in the comment there doesn't seem to be a good reason for shelling out to the script at all: since it is Python, just import it and call it in the normal way.

Comment: Thankyou for your considered response to my admittedly strange question, I will attempt to implement your suggestions. I spent a while reading the documentation but somehow skipped over the get_context_data method.